# Remove Vertical Indentation in Tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, justification

I have been using the tabular function with specific width columns that fill the page as so:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.18\textwidth}|p{0.82\textwidth}}
```

I then wanted to have the first column to be left justified. For some reason, I cannot used raggedright so I did this:

```
\begin{flushleft}\textbf{FIRST COLUMN} \newline \footnotesize{Date} 
\end{flushleft}& SECOND COLUMN\\
```

However, by using flush left, the FIRST COLUMN text now has a vertical indent which wasn't there before and I never asked for if that makes sense. This is a little frustrating as sometimes one solution just creates another problem for no immediately apparent reason. I am new to this so I know it's down to something I have done/haven't done though.

With flushleft:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.18\textwidth}|p{0.82\textwidth}}
\begin{flushleft}\textbf{FIRST COLUMN} \newline \footnotesize{Date} 
\end{flushleft}& SECOND COLUMN\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

And Without:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.18\textwidth}|p{0.82\textwidth}}
\textbf{FIRST COLUMN} \newline \footnotesize{Date} & SECOND COLUMN\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

At the moment, I am aware that the alignment looks the same but the real words just don't look right when fully justified so it has to be left-justified.

Comment: you can use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.8\textwidth}`  so `\\ ` ends the table row, but note that your tables are wider than text width,

Comment: unrelated but size commands do not take an argument so `\footnotesize{Date}` should be `\footnotesize Date`

Comment: Thank you David!
I found a solution that works in the end:
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.18\textwidth}|p{0.82\textwidth}}
\raggedright \textbf FIRST COLUMN \newline \footnotesize DATE 
& s

Comment: yes if you only want that cell ragged, the `>` syntax I showed (array package) specifes all cells in that column to be ragged, note that `{@{} p{0.18\textwidth}|p{0.82\textwidth}} ` is at least 18pt (`3\tabcolsep`) too wide as you are missing `@{}` at the end not accounting for the \tabcolsep either side of the rule, and it may also be .4pt too wide for the width of the rule (depending on which packages you have loaded)

Comment: I used the @{} to remove horizontal indentation in the first column. Should I add it at the end too? Also, I thought the fractions (0.18 plus 0.82) had to add to 1 otherwise the text would not reach across the page. It has to line up with the rest of the text in the document you see

Comment: if you remove the padding on the left normal to remove it on the right otherwise the table looks unbalanced. and `p{3cm}` means that the width for line breaking in the cell is 3cm (like \parbox{3cm}` ) the actual column has `\tabcolsep` (6pt by default) either side unless you use `@{}` to supporess that but then the text in one column would touch the text in the next. The vertical rule may or may not increase the width of the table by the width of the rule depending on code you have not shown (with array package it does increase the table width).

Comment: But you don't need to guess or ask me: tex will scream about overfull hboxes if the table is too wide (never ignore warnings in the log:-)

Comment: Im sorry David I dont understand what you mean. I'm new to this so certain terms are hard to understand. I haven't used p{3cm} anywhere in the code. And I'm not familiar with the parbox syntax either or tabcolsep. My text doesn't touch the text in the next column but I do get blue error messages saying underfull hbox and overfull hbox.

Comment: if you write `p{3cm}` the lines of text in the column are3cm wide but they do not touch the next column as each columns adds 6pt white space either side. so the actual column from `p{0.18\textwidth}` is .18\textwidth+12pt wide and  `p{0.82\textwidth}` is .82\textwidth+12pt wide so you are 24pt over you removed 6pt from the left with `@{}` but that means that you are still 18pt over.

Comment: I see! The problem I now face though is if I decrease the decimal values to fit in the left over 18pt, The text doesnt line up with the rest of the text in the document. The text in the table doesnt go as far to the right as I want it too. I need it to align with the rest of the text outside of the table. How do I do with without getting the blue errors?

Comment: you could do the arithmetic but easiest is to use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{.2\textwidth}|X@{}`  where in tabularx X columns are an automatically calculated width (see tabularx tag for hundreds of examples on this site

Comment: Thank you David!

Comment: Hi Dave, I tried using that line of code for tabularx and it didnt work. Am I missing anything in the preamble or something? Here is what I used:

Comment: \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{.2\linewidth}|X@{}}
hello & hello
\end{tabularx}